# Invoke-RestMethod convert hashtable to json array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send a request to an API that requires the body to be a json array. How can I convert the parameters hash table into a json array?

```
$parameters =@{

                "sn" = "CND3210W9M"
                "pn" = "D5H49AV"
          }
 $post = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://blah.com/queries" -Method Post -Body ($parameters | ConvertTo-Json) -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'
```

The API example shows the array below as a valid body

```
 [
   {
     "sn": "CND3210W9M",
     "pn": "D5H49AV"
   }
 ]
```

Comment: How about `$parameters = @();
$parameters.Add(@{
    "sn" = "CND3210W9M"
    "pn" = "D5H49AV"
});`?

Comment: Your expected request body is not valid json. Every item in json has an identifier.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Does that code work for you, I just tried it and got a few errors

Comment: @Eris I didn't make up the example, What I put down in the example is word by word the example on their site and when I use that in their "Try it now" section it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your request is expecting valid json, it might look something like this:

```
$body = @{ 
parameters =  
    @( # Make this an array
        @{ # of hashtables
            "sn" = "CND3210W9M"
            "pn" = "D5H49AV"
    } ) }

$body | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output:

```
{
    "parameters":  [
                       {
                           "pn":  "D5H49AV",
                           "sn":  "CND3210W9M"
                       }
                   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eris, I tried using your code but it returned an extra {} which the API didn't like.

In the end I ended up just using a here string and moving on. It's not very elegant but couldn't get the API to respond properly otherwise.

```
 $body = @"
 [
  {
     "sn": "$sn",
     "pn": "$pn"
  }
]
"@
```